# How can is display 2 models in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model

to learn rails i have written a little webapp, to track which employee is using which computer and what software is installed on it. I started with 
`rails generate scaffold Client deviceName:string deviceComment:text` 
Everything works fine and i can add, edit or destroy Cients. Now i want to track the software which is installed on every machine. This time i only created a model with 
`rails generate model Software title:string licence:string` 
My question is now, how can i "add" Softwaretitle and the licencenumber?

i want to show the Label for the softwaretitle and the licencenumber on the same site where i can add new clients. Precise on the clients/new site.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Regards,
Buk

Comment: Try to bind two models with `has_many` and `belongs_to` assotiation

Comment: Do you want one form that creates both models with one request or two separate forms on one page ?

Comment: No. One form that handles both models. One form to rule them all ... :) *scnr*

Answer (score 1):

You need setup relationship between models, you can read it there http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html After that you can call software that related to the client